# How do you say that you're ‘high’ (from smoking marijuana) in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do you say that you’re ‘high’ (from smoking marijuana) in German?

Is the expression limited to marijuana or is it used in other instances as well?

Also if there is a term for people who smoke a lot of weed, that’d be interesting to know.

Comment: Also amusing as it is, please try to be more constructive than what I found with google http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_say_I_am_high_in_German   :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- "Bekifft" is the accepted word that is used in public life and that everyone will understand. A parent or teacher might ask "Bist du bekifft?"; however when speaking among peers, the users themselves will usually not use the word, but one of the many slang terms. (At least that was the way in my days; I doubt it has changed.)
- "High" and "stoned" are less formal, and will be understood by most people.
- "Dicht" and "breit" are used to describe any kind of intoxication, usually from alcohol, but also cannabis.
- In a *totally* formal context like, say, in a police report, there will be special formalized constructions like "Unter Drogeneinfluß" or similar.

The slang terms to describe the condition are too numerous to be listed. When their use is appropriate and when not depends strongly on context and audience - as everywhere, youth slang is highly volatile and cryptic, so tread carefully.

The most common way to describe a person who smokes a lot of cannabis is "Kiffer".

Comment: I would say *dicht* and *breit* apply only to forms of intoxication that numb you, or at least not on those that energize you. You probably wouldn't say you're *breit* on speed.

Comment: Actually, in my teenage days, parents/teachers wouldn't use "bekifft". So this still seems kind of informal to me.

Comment: A regional term is "blass", I think it's from the Mainz region.

Comment: I think I've seen "Bist du breit?" the most (in animation movies). Also I am not native.

Comment: ``zugedröhnt`` is also one that i encountered in all of germany.

Answer (score 13):

**Formal language**

- bekifft sein
- (Marijuana) geraucht haben

**Informal language**

- breit sein
- stoned sein
- high sein

**Very informal**

- dicht sein*
- prall sein
- tot sein
- zu sein*
- voll sein*
- drauf sein
- hacke sein*
- eingeraucht sein [austrian]

**Very uncommon**

I heard these some time, but only a vew times so these expressions are very uncommon

- einen im Brett haben
- im Grünen Paradies sein
- mit den blauen Elefanten fliegen (I nearly chocked on my own laughter upon hearing this)

[*] also used to say you're completely drunk

Comment: dict.cc also lists _eingeraucht_ as [österr.].

Comment: ich kenn noch "hacke" ^^

Comment: *Breit* is often also used to describe being drunk, esp. from beer. I think this carries strong connotations to also being a bit numb and lazy as a result of being intoxicated. And do people really still say *stoned*? I've only heard (*ahem*) old people say it.

Comment: I wouldn't say "bekifft sein" is _formal_ language.

Comment: "Straff sein" is a wide-spread term at least in Berlin (very informal).

Comment: Ergänzung: bedröhnt

Answer (score 6):

A regular user of THC is a *Kiffer* (m.).

The state of being intoxicated from THC is *bekifft*.

> Alex ist ein *Kiffer*; ständig hat er einen *Joint* in der Hand. Er *kifft* jeden Tag. Wenn er *bekifft* ist, bekommt er oft einen *Fressflash*.

(*Fressflash* is a very colloquial term describing the hunger attack that is often associated with using THC. It is very informal.)

Comment: It's called _the munchies_ ;)

Comment: … and they mostly describe “the munchies” as “Fress-Kick”.

Answer (score 3):

> bekifft sein

*"High"* is probably used as well, though.

The usage of *bekifft* can also refer to simple acts of stupidity, but is still based on the meaning of "being high from smoking marijuana".

> Bist Du bekifft, oder was?